# How to properly parse XML with SAX?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

I am receiving an XML document from a REST service which shall be parsed using SAX. Please see the following example which was generated out of the XSD.

Setting up the parser is not a problem. My main problem is the actual processing in the `startElement()`, `endElement()` methods etc. I don't understand how to extract the items I need and store them as they are somewhat "nested".

#### Example

The `ConnectionList` can occur once or twice and may contain any number of `Connection` elements which -in turn- have details about a connection. Basically, I need a list of all connections with their `Date`, `Transfers` and `Time`. Do I have to create one class per element?

As far as I got it I somehow need to do the following:
If the parser comes across a...

- `ConnectionList`: Create new `ConnectionList` object and put it into a list of `ConnectionList`s
- `Connection`: Create a new Connection object and put it into a list of Connections
- `Date`, `Transfers`, `Time` (only if parent is `Duration`): Store the node value in the current `Connection` object

I'd really appreciate any help, hint, idea, snippet how I can achieve this.

Thanks :-)

Robert

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Err code="r5E5a1Wm" text="tk-gWYbw" level="E"/>
    <Err code="takVDd34" text="XtvyjmjPuscK" level="E"/>
    <Err code="hQ1-:aDQ" text="YWc5qtY.gkwCeJW2S" level="E"/>
    <ConRes dir="R">
        <Err code="ZfwPC:tj" text="RKKFuLXoM0oOfp3a" level="E"/>
        <Err code="bhDjSJPa" text="BJoHuOMdwzhcddW" level="E"/>
        <Err code="CX-NhK9r" text="j55qy-WiNPXu" level="E"/>
        <ConResCtxt b="1" f="1">0815</ConResCtxt>
        <ConnectionList type="IV">
            <Err code="WI3WX.jo" text="rK3H5jwa-Zfen3" level="E"/>
            <Connection id="ID000">
                <Overview>
                    <Date>b3lcM_Yiyq7dqL9</Date>
                    <Departure>
                        <BasicStop type="NORMAL" index="-1086549314">
                            <Address externalId="t.EdKe93xkqFqLwPzgd-4vHSJemy8"
                                externalStationNr="1332105793" name="fdREYJPu83WV503V8szdCX"
                                x="951177990" y="-1579782776" z="1807457957" type="WGS84"/>
                        </BasicStop>
                    </Departure>
                    <Arrival>
                        <BasicStop type="NORMAL" index="1897526979">
                            <Address externalId="l7h_GTUit6fv" externalStationNr="-1670310329"
                                name="WJznDTzkTvyET51pfr7X" x="-1738098662" y="-170353174"
                                z="-475585957" type="WGS84"/>
                        </BasicStop>
                    </Arrival>
                    <Transfers>dZbgZfDH8j1hb1i</Transfers>
                    <Duration>
                        <Time>00d00:18:00</Time>
                    </Duration>
                    <ServiceDays> </ServiceDays>
                    <Products>
                        <Product cat="qmrN2dShHJp"/>
                        <Product cat="Hg"/>
                        <Product cat="nurxhdl3w.P0x7FRv2J3UoF"/>
                    </Products>
                    <ContextURL url="http://FzgEqiVC/"/>
                </Overview>
            </Connection>
            <Connection id="ID004">
                <Overview>
                    <Date>W5a47DRkc7XDZjhwq_s5Un.</Date>
                    <Departure>
                        <BasicStop type="NORMAL" index="-1014429844">
                            <Address externalId="RMnzjEFOTTdM1oaAUw" externalStationNr="1429101638"
                                name="HF-1" x="1005198487" y="570832676" z="975615566" type="WGS84"
                            />
                        </BasicStop>
                    </Departure>
                    <Arrival>
                        <BasicStop type="NORMAL" index="-58308182">
                            <Address externalId="rVdwdQvAukfj2QcA7b3OSdGOyW"
                                externalStationNr="1142334006" name="g" x="-1791416159"
                                y="-541300941" z="478129823" type="WGS84"/>
                        </BasicStop>
                    </Arrival>
                    <Transfers>GG56XN6zgiJF804mE_N4o</Transfers>
                    <Duration> </Duration>
                    <ServiceDays> </ServiceDays>
                    <Products>
                        <Product cat="fs_Oyoy9NYBai-qaxbty6j9Y7r1St"/>
                        <Product cat="P2CbaSGpC"/>
                        <Product cat="CGZrqSIDM6M4kUlb8_xZ8jRlH4c"/>
                    </Products>
                    <ContextURL url="http://JkRhuXtu/"/>
                </Overview>
            </Connection>
        </ConnectionList>
        <ConnectionList type="IV">
            <Err code="0lFWRY2X" text="KLmdczFRhV" level="E"/>
            <Connection id="ID012">
                <Overview>
                    <Date>t8mn634zjCZsRPyxj_e_-UYMH</Date>
                    <Departure>
                        <BasicStop type="NORMAL" index="-2095085423">
                            <Address externalId="ftKAFG-Uk7x" externalStationNr="1390920810"
                                name="JQrQXOQbm.FLaCMeSiTYjT" x="1970142849" y="-655980297"
                                z="2102464970" type="WGS84"/>
                        </BasicStop>
                    </Departure>
                    <Arrival>
                        <BasicStop type="NORMAL" index="1552118247">
                            <Address externalId="qcBpeuPDRzvSt1o" externalStationNr="-1133118359"
                                name="AJiJOB1t" x="-1422533132" y="-1158953133" z="484831466"
                                type="WGS84"/>
                        </BasicStop>
                    </Arrival>
                    <Transfers>D0MiUwW9nuuM_uykvawg2C07pwHL</Transfers>
                    <Duration> </Duration>
                    <ServiceDays> </ServiceDays>
                    <Products>
                        <Product cat="LpGOZbLDbJm"/>
                        <Product cat="JIv-szQVX2icPb"/>
                        <Product cat="Q7-pthWoOT"/>
                    </Products>
                    <ContextURL url="http://zGWgivvi/"/>
                </Overview>
                <IList>
                    <I header="ze4Wt3hVD-DvjujY6QKae" text="lVwB4RxAHcYq3.F"
                        uriCustom="iVjQJCoU1MVOv2Z9lwarP"/>
                    <I header="z-i.au59soMzXLZCbV" text="PoTP" uriCustom="ksrbwEH6scNR"/>
                    <I header="N" text="jHDA4" uriCustom="ub95811lMIa_495ZbPOuNWL0rRWh"/>
                </IList>
                <CommentList>
                    <Comment id="ID013">
                        <Text lang="EN"> </Text>
                        <Text lang="FR"> </Text>
                        <Text lang="PL"> </Text>
                    </Comment>
                    <Comment id="ID014">
                        <Text lang="DK"> </Text>
                        <Text lang="IT"> </Text>
                        <Text lang="IT"> </Text>
                    </Comment>
                    <Comment id="ID015">
                        <Text lang="MACRO"> </Text>
                        <Text lang="IT"> </Text>
                        <Text lang="EN"> </Text>
                    </Comment>
                </CommentList>
            </Connection>
        </ConnectionList>
    </ConRes>
</ResC>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way I've found (so far) of parsing XML using SAX is to use a stack and conditional statements in the relevant callbacks. [Here's an article describing it](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/06/26/xml.html?page=2), and my summary of it:

The basic premise is that as you parse the document, you create objects to store the parsed data, pushing them onto the stack as you go, peeking at the top of the stack to add data to the current element, and at the end of each element popping it off the stack and storing it in the parent.

The effect is that you parse the tree of elements depth first, and at the end of each branch you roll it back into the parent until you're left with a single object (such as your ConnectionList) that contains all of the parsed data ready to be used. Essentially, you end up with a series of objects that mirror the structure of the original XML

That means you need some data objects that can store the data in the same structure as the XML. Complex elements will normally become classes, while simple elements will normally be attributes within classes. The root element is often represented by a list of some kind.

To start with, you create a stack object to hold the data as you parse it.

Then, at the start of each element you identify what type it is using `localName.equals()` method, create an instance of the appropriate class, and push it into the Stack. If the element is a simple element, you will probably model that as an attribute in the class representing the parent element, and you will need a series of flags that tells the parser if such an element is encountered and what element it is so it can be processed in the `characters()` method.

The actual data is read using the `characters()` method, and again you use conditional logic to determine what to do with the data, based on the value of the flag. Essentially, you peek at the top of the stack and use the appropriate method to write the data into the object, converting from text where necessary.

At the end of each element, you pop the top of the stack and use `localName.equals()` again to determine how to store it in the object before it (e.g. which setter method needs to be called)

When you reach the end of the document you should have captured all the data in the document.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I think that is what I've been looking for :-)

Comment: The first advice I usually gives about stax/sax parsing is to not use them whenever they can be avoided...

Answer (score 6):

Your SAX event handler should act as a state machine.  Your structure is pretty deep, so the state machine will be a bit complex; but this is the basic approach:

All variables are member variables.

When you encounter a startElement event, you instantiate an object representing that element then put the object on a stack (or set a flag indicating what value you are working with).

When you encounter a text event, read the text and set the appropriate value based on the flag you set in the previous step.

When you encounter a endElement event, you pull the current object off the stack and call the setter on the object that is now on the top of the stack.

When you exhaust the document, you should only have one object left on the stack which represents everything you've read.

Answer (score 2):

SAX parsers are a bit like looking at a large picture through a tiny spy hole.

The callback will present you with a single piece of the XML structure at a time. It wont give you any clues as to where you are in the document only a single piece of data is presented,. The element name, the attribute name/value or the text contents.

Your program needs to track where you are in the document. If you are parsing on the fly a simple stack structure will do -- you push the name onto the stack when you get a "beginelement" and you pop the stack on an "endelement".

If you find yourself building a tree structure I would switch to a DOM parser as whatever you write will be a pale and buggy shadow of something like XERCES.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a reasonably small xml document and the memory/throughput constraints aren't prohibitive to an in memory solution, then you could use JAXB instead. You can generate the required classes from the XSD and simply unmarshall the xml into java objects. If you must use a streaming parser, then consider using StAX instead, I generally find this more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, Ellis. I forgot to mention that all this will be running on an Android device which only supports SAX and DOM natively.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you have a couple choices:

1. Use custom objects to map the XML to, these objects will encapsulate more objects much like the XML elements nest.
2. Do a generic parsing and traverse the DOM via relative elements.

To my knowledge there are some tools out there such as JAXB which will generate your classes based on XSD's, but they can sometimes come with a price as generated code often does.

If you go with option 1 and "roll your own" you'll need to provide methods for unmarshaling and marshaling that go to and from XML and most likely Strings. Something like:

```
<Foo>
  <Bar>
    <Baz></Baz>
  </Bar>
  <Thing></Thing>
</Foo>

// pseudo-code!
//In Foo.java
unmarshal( Element element ) {
 unmarshalBar( element );
 unmarshalThing( element );
}

unmarshalBar( Element element ) {
 //...verify that the element is bar
 bar = new Bar();
 bar.unmarshal( element );
}

//In Bar.java
unmarshal( Element element ) {
 unmarshalBaz( element );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I usually put objects on a stack, and push/pop them while parsing the XML file (particularly useful if objects are nested, but that's not your case).

If you want a simpler approach, you need at a pointer to the current ConnectionList and to the current Connection. Since you already know the structure of your file, this could be easier than using a stack-based parser.